# Setting a constant from a variable value

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to set the path of my database as a constant.

The problem is that the path is stored in a INI file and the variable is set when Outlook is launched. VBA won't compile if the constant isn't hardcoded.

The reason why I want to use a constant is because, for some reasons, after a few hours/days with Outlook running, it sometimes seems to lose the value of its variables (never experienced this problem with a hardcoded constant). The path variable just get emptied, and then when VBA tries to reach the database, the user gets an error.

I can't hardcode the path just because some users don't use the same server UNC path. This path might change once a year or so, it's easier to just edit the INI file and restart Outlook than ask for a programmer to edit the right line in the code on each user's computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could store it in a non-constant variable, create a `getPath` function that returns the content of variable, unless it is empty in which case it fetches the value. Then you use the getPath in your code.

Comment: True, I think it could get the job done. Is there any reason why Outlook VBA tends to lose its variables over the day? Pretty annoying. I've experienced some problems like that when I was doing VBA with Access but it's usually when an error handler is triggered or something wrong happens, while in Outlook just the time seems to be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the value of a constant at run-time.  Those values are set when the code is compiled (even if you don't explicitly compile VBA code it is still done Just-In Time (JIT) in the background).

If you don't want to be constantly running the lookup code (because it is inefficient, for example), than you can use a static variable within a function:

```vb
Function GetDbPath() As String
    Static DbPath As String
    If Len(DbPath) = 0 Then 
        DbPath = 'your code here'
    End If
    GetDbPath = DbPath
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, same as assylias comment above. It should be my final solution to this problem. Still wondering why Outlook deletes its variables after some idle time.